# boomla: how to place text on image

Tags: boomla

This DOM object has no specific class selector applied to it, so I can't select it via CSS.

[image]

I could use some first-child hack or change the `/apps/page/.Class/*` files but I don't feel like either is a clean solution.

I want to have an image with some text in front of it.
Shall I modify the HTML of my page? I could also change the CSS of a markdown or text (app), but it doesn't feel like a tidy solution.
I also thought of having the image as a background pic, then life would be easy :)

What is the best solution?

Here is where I am:
[image: image placed on my website]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a html-1 content and apply some css to it.

Here are the files you should create with their [file types]:

```
content [html-1]
content/style.css [css-1]
content/style.css/background.png [image-1]
```

The `content` file should store your HTML:

```html
<div class="-container">
    <div class="-text">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

The `style.css` file could then apply the background image and make your text prettier:

```css
.-container {
    height: 400px;
    background: url(background.png) no-repeat center center transparent;
}
.-text {
    color: red;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center
    line-height: 400px;
}
```

(The image url will be expanded by the css-1 app.)